# after submit of form, get ID of entry into another table

Tags: php, mysql, forms

My current form submits data to two different tables, and I want the auto_incremented value from one table to also be stored in the second table.

```
<form method="POST" action="addcocktail.php" >
                    Cocktail Name: <input type="text" name="cocktailname" /> 
                    How To: <input type="text" name="howto" /> 
                    <br> 
                    <select id="selectingred1" name="selectingred1">
                      <?php
                      $sql = "SELECT ingredientID, name FROM tblIngredient ".
                      "ORDER BY name";

                      $rs = mysql_query($sql);

                      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
                      {
                        echo "<option value=\"".$row['ingredientID']."\">".$row['name']."</option>\n  ";
                      }
                      ?>
                    </select>
                    <select id="quantity1" name="quantity1">
                      <option></option>
                      <option>1</option>
                      <option>2</option>
                      <option>3</option>
                      <option>4</option>
                    </select>
                    <br>
<input type="submit" value="add" />
                </form>
```

addcocktail.php:

```
 <?php include("databasecon.php"); ?>

<?php
mysql_select_db("mwheywood", $con);

//insert cocktail details
$sql="INSERT INTO tblCocktail (name, howto)
VALUES
('$_POST[cocktailname]','$_POST[howto]')";

$sql2="INSERT INTO tblRecipe (ingredientID, quantity)
VALUES
('$_POST[selectingred1]','$_POST[quantity1]'),
('$_POST[selectingred2]','$_POST[quantity2]'),
('$_POST[selectingred3]','$_POST[quantity3]'),
('$_POST[selectingred4]','$_POST[quantity4]')";



if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: you fail at life' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "cocktail added";

if (!mysql_query($sql2,$con))
  {
  die('Error: you fail at life' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "ingredients added";

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

so to put it simply, when I submit my form. I want the "cocktailID" of the posted data to "tblCocktail" to also save into "tblRecipe"

Answer (score 2):

after executing the insert query, you can get the insert id if succeeded with [mysql_insert_id()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) function.

Comment: hmm Im not quite sure how it knows to insert the cocktailID for each select box entry AFTER the insert statements?

Comment: Think about it, you'll find. You got all the functions, there's only putting them together left.